# Bigint (bigbit) library

Tags: c++, biginteger

I'm looking for a c++ class/library that provides 1024 bit and bigger integers and bit operations like: 
 - bit shifting, 
 - bitwise OR/AND,
 - position first zero bit

speed is crucial, so it would have to be implemented with some SIMD assembly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several, including [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), but for speed, the best is likely [TTmath](http://www.ttmath.org/ttmath). TTmath's design decision to use templated fixed lengths at compiletime  lets it be quite fast.

Answer (score 4):

try [gmp library](http://gmplib.org/). It is a C library. Beginning with GMP 4.0 a C++ wrapper is bundled with the release.

Answer (score 1):

Just consider the big integer multiplication, the TTmath Library use Karatsuba algorithm, which has time complexity $O(n^{1.585})$.
The fastest algorithm is $O(n log n log log n)$, using FFT.