# int128 on Linux for Intel compiler

Tags: c++, linux, intel, icc, int128

Linux 2.6.32

Intel compiler: icpc version 13.0.1 (gcc version 4.4.6 compatibility)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    std::cerr << sizeof (__uint128_t) << std::endl;     
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `16`

So, type `__uint128_t` exists.
However, working with `__uint128_t` produces compilation and run errors.

Programs:

```
// File int01.cpp
#include <cstdint>
int main()
{
uint128_t val128 = 0;
return 0;
}


// File int02.cpp
#include <cstdint>
int main()
{
__uint128_t val128 = 0;
return 0;
}


// File int03.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
int main()
{
__uint128_t val128 = 0;
std::cerr << val128 << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Compilations:

> icpc int01.cpp

/usr/include/c++/4.4.6/c++0x_warning.h(31): catastrophic error: #error directive: This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
  #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming \
   ^

compilation aborted for int01.cpp (code 4)

> icpc int01.cpp -std=c++0x

int01.cpp(4): error: identifier "uint128_t" is undefined
    uint128_t val128 = 0;
    ^

compilation aborted for int01.cpp (code 2)

> icpc int02.cpp -std=c++0x

// No errors

> icpc int03.cpp -std=c++0x

int03.cpp(6): error: more than one operator "<<" matches these operands:

```
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned long) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned short) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned long long) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
        operand types are: std::ostream << __uint128_t
std::cerr << val128 << std::endl;
          ^
```

compilation aborted for int03.cpp (code 2)

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What compilation errors? From what code? What runtime errors?

Comment: What compilation command? Which libraries are linked? It should be `uint128_t` not `__uint128_t` with `#include <stdint.h>` or better `#include <cstdint>` (in C++)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Interestingly I can not seem to get `uinit128_t` to work on any compilers on Live Work Space although they all accept `__uint128_t`, this previous post seems to indicate it is experimental and platform dependent http://stackoverflow.com/a/11660651/1708801

Answer (score 0):

As for 1) and 2) everything I read basically says that this is [experimental and platform dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11660651/1708801). Although @Basile suggested that it should be `uint128_t` I can not find a compiler `Intel`, `gcc` nor `clang` that support anything but `__uint128_t`, you can try out various compilers at [Live Work Space](http://liveworkspace.org/). This is [my attempt](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1UzCdI) at this problem.

As for 3) it would seem that there is no version of of these streams that support `__uint128_t` since it is experimental perhaps that should be surprising. This previous thread [how to print __uint128_t number using gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656241/how-to-print-uint128-t-number-using-gcc) shows some alternatives.

Is there any reason why you don't explore some of the [Bigint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055661/bigint-bigbit-library) libraries out there?

Comment: I need exactly builtin int128 for AtomicObject