# Using extremely large integer holding 3001 digits

Tags: c++

For example, how can I use the result of 1000^1000 for arithmetic? I don't think there's a library that can accommodate that, all I see at most is 100 number digits.

Comment: 1000^1000 only has one significant digit, so that's probably not that big a deal.  Have you looked into [GMP](http://gmplib.org)?

Comment: boost arbitrary arithmetic has no limits as far as I know.  Why do you need such large ints?

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055661/bigint-bigbit-library

Comment: You may not think that there is such a library, but did you try google? The first result for "C++ extremely large integer library" points you to [Matt McCuthchen's Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) which also links to GMP. Did you try searching StackOverflow before posting? "Large Integer Library" yields a lot of results, all useful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) or [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multiprecision/).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) or [Boost-Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) or [TTmath](http://www.ttmath.org/).

Or, you might challenge yourself to write a low level representation that handles longer than standard bit representations, and do arithmetic with it.

Stick with the first option though, if it does the job you have in mind.