# How to store extremely large numbers?

Tags: c++, data-structures, int, large-data

For example I have a factorial program that needs to save really huge integers that can be 50+ digits long. The absolute maximum primitive data type in C++ is `unsigned long long int` with a maximum value `18446744073709551615` which is only 20 digits long. Here's the link to the limits of C++: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

How do I store numbers that are larger than that in a variable of some sort?

Comment: By using a bigint library. GNU GMP is a good one to begin with.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you already have a boost dependency (which many people these days do), you can use the boost [multi-precision library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html). In fact, it already has an example of a [factorial program](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/egs/factorials.html) that can support output up to 128 bits, though extending it further is pretty trivial.

Comment: Kudos for pointing out to that one, I didn't know boost had grown such.

Answer (score 9):

You'll have to use a bigint or bignum implementation. There are some libraries out there like this: http://gmplib.org/

Some more info and a list of libraries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum

Answer (score 5):

You can use array. First you should copy that giant number array,then use comma after 19 digits:

```
unsigned long long int num[]= {
        7316717653133062491,9225119674426574742,3553491949349698352,0,312774506326239578,3180169848018694788,
        5184385861560789112,9494954595017379583,3195285320880551112,5406987471585238630,5071569329096329522,
        7443043557668966489,5044524452316173185,6403098711121722383,1136222989342338030,8135336276614282806,
        4444866452387493035,8907296290491560440,7723907138105158593,0,7960866701724271218,8399879790879227492,
        1901699720888093776,6572733300105336788,1220235421809751254,5405947522435258490,7711670556013604839,
        5864467063244157221,5539753697817977846,1740649551492908625,6932197846862248283,9722413756570560574,
        9026140797296865241,4535100474821663704,8440319989000889524,3450658541227588666,8811642717147992444,
        2928230863465674813,9191231628245861786,6458359124566529476,5456828489128831426,0,7690042242190226710,
        5562632111110937054,4217506941658960408,0,7198403850962455444,3629812309878799272,4428490918884580156,
        1660979191338754992,0,0,5240636899125607176,0,6058861164671094050,7754100225698315520,0,0,
        5593572972571636269,5618826704282524836,0,0,8232575304207529634,50};
```

Comment: why comma after 19 digits?

Comment: Because of size of 
long long int

Comment: The other solution is bigint or bignum implementation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1055661/8678385
You can find the BigInt library here.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to store very big number which are below:

1. string
2. File
3. Link list
4. Vector/Dynamic array

Note: Please don't use array to avoid memory problem issues.

Comment: How about static array or global array?

Comment: static array or global array is not good option to go because if continuous memory is not available then you can't store very big number.