# How to solve this easy in c or c++?

Tags: c++, c

```
print 10**1000 % 7
```

In C I get a syntax error because it exceeds the memory limit I guess. Can I somehow solve this easy in C or C++, such that it would give me a modulo of 10 to the power of 1000?

Comment: Have you tried `long`?

Comment: 10 multiplied by 1000 dereferenced?

Comment: Don't just spam languages in the tags, the answer depends on the language.

Comment: To represent so big numbers, that long long does not suffice, "bignums" are used

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060242/how-to-store-extremely-large-numbers

Comment: Are you asking about specifically `m^n%p` expressions - in which case there are tricks to be played. If you are asking "how do I deal with really large numbers in general", then it's a different question.

Comment: i am asking about m^n%p

Comment: So what is the question? You seem to be asking how to do this in C or C++. But you chose a python answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to that not being valid syntax in C/C++, it's bad practice in python.

If you do

```
pow(10,1000,7)
```

It will use modular exponentiation so it will be much faster than doing

```
10 ** 1000 % 7
```

Comment: Which library are you getting that `pow` from?

Comment: @juanchopanza pow is a builtin

Comment: In which language? AFAIK C or C++ don't have built-in functions. They may have some operators, but `pow` is not one of them.

Comment: @juanchopanza I was referring to his code which is written in python.

Comment: Oh I see. But they are asking how to do this in C or C++, so you're not answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `pow` for power operation. here the size of result is large value so you need to divide the problem into smaller part and solve smaller ones to get the solution in c or you'll need to handle large numbers.
you can apply modulus rules to reduce the problem as,

```
10^1000 % 7 =((10%7)^1000)%7
10^1000 % 7 =(((((10^10)%7)^10)%7)^10)%7
```

combine these rules and use to reduce the numbers generated in steps by (mod 10).use inbuilt `pow()` function in c to get power of number as  X^y=pow(x,y)

Comment: The rule you use "a^b (mod p) = a^(b mod p) (mod p)" is only valid if `a` and `p` are coprime. Counterexample - 2^10 (mod 8) != 2^2 (mod 8)

Comment: @MattMcNabb ok. thanks. but the rule i specified is like 2^10(mod 8)=(2^2(mod 8))^5 (mod 8).

Answer (score 2):

The most general way to solve these types of big-integer problems in small (e.g. 32-bit) registers is with [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), and taking modulo at each step.  E.g. 10^10 is still too big to fit in a 32-bit int, though you could probably just use a long these days.

Answer (score 1):

In C (and C++ too AFAIK) this is not a valid syntax. You can use `pow` function for exponentiation. But keep in mind that return value of `pow` is `double` and modulo operator works for `int`. You need some cautions.

```
long result = (long)pow(10, 1000);
result = result % 7;
```

Comment: A float Pow followed by a modulo operation won't yield any meaningful result. Same problem with using e.g. Pascal's Math.Pow.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort; Hey, yor point is valid! Adding to the answer.

Comment: The improvement doesn't help. Floating point numbers only have about 18 significant digits and 10^1000 has a thousand. One  needs big integer, or rewriting (LearningC's) for this

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to reduce the terms by the modulus.  The general formula is

a<sup>b</sup> mod c  ≡ (a mod c)<sup>(b mod φ(c))</sup> mod c

So in this case you get

10<sup>1000</sup> mod 7 = (10 mod 7)<sup>(1000 mod φ(7))</sup> mod 7.

10 mod 7 = 3

φ(7) = 6

1000 mod 6 = 4

3<sup>4</sup> = 81

81 mod 7 = 4

so 10<sup>1000</sup> mod 7 = 4

Answer (score 0):

- in C and C++ there's no `**` operator, you have to use the `pow` function, that however works only for floating-point types; and the % operator works only for integral types, for FP types you have to use `fmod`;
- anyhow, if you have insert some constant 10**n you would just write `1En` (say, `1E42`);
- .... but there's no standard type able to hold a number as big as 1E1000; even if some FP type were able to hold it, you couldn't reliably use `fmod` on it, due to the finite precision of the mantissa.

So, how does Python do? Under the hood, beyond the range of "normal" types it uses an arbitrary precision library. You can do the same in your C++ program, providing such library (for example you could use GMP).

***But***: the expression you provide can be calculated without actually computing 10**1000 and its modulus. Read [Modulus power of big numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287144/modulus-power-of-big-numbers)