# How to print numbers bigger than 2^32 in 32-bit C++?

Tags: c++, biginteger

I'm writing a program that generates large prime numbers. Bigger than 2^32. How do I generate such big numbers in 32-bit C++? I use Windows 7 on 32-bit processor. I know I could get 64-bit support buy buying a new 64-bit computer, but it's not an option currently.

Comment: Haha, good one. You don't need to buy a new computer in order to be able to declare have 64-bit variables in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060242/how-to-store-extremely-large-numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `long long` or include `stdint.h` or `cstdint` and use `int64_t` and `uint64_t`.
In addition to this, you can refer to Windows data types at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

From this list, you can use `DWORDLONG`, `DWORD64` or `INT64`.

Answer (score 2):

To *print* the number, use `%lld` with printf:

```
long long variable;
printf( "your long long variable: %lld", variable );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `long long`, which is at least 64-bit, and it's available in 32-bit machines as well.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `long long` is at least 8 bits and at least as large as `long`. Nothing more is guaranteed by the language.

Comment: @DonReba: The standard guarantees a minimum range of representable values for `long long`. A range which can only be satisfied by 64 bits or more.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I don't see it. Where does the standard do that?
"Objects declared as characters (char) shall be large enough to store any member of the implementation's basic character set." (C++11 3.9.1.1)
That's it for minimum ranges.

Comment: @DonReba: The C99 standard library defines the values in 5.2.4.2.1, which defines the contents of the `<limits.h>` header. The C++11 standard, in 18.3.3, references the C99 standard, explicitly stating the the contents of the `<climits>` header are the same as `<limits.h>` in the C standard.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It also notes that "the types of the constants defined by macros in <climits> are not required to match the types to which the macros refer." The header does not place any constraints on the fundamental C++ types.

Comment: @DonReba: I don't see the relevance of that quote. All it is saying is that, for example, `SHRT_MIN` (which refers to the type `short int`) might be defined as the value `-32767`, even though that numeric constant is not of type `short int`, but rather of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

There also is the [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library for signed integers of arbitrary size even >2^64. The C++ interface makes the variables behave just like normal ints via operator overloading.