# C++ type with 200 digits after decimal point?

Tags: c++, calculator, precision, bigdecimal

I have a project for my school, and the goal of it is create simple "Virtual Machine" who execute operations.

To do that, we can store some numbers with types, they are:
int8, int16, int32, float, double, and big decimal.

The only type i don't know is the "big decimal", it is describe with: "The maximum of digits to display after the decimal point is are float(7), double(15), bigdecimal(200)."

So big decimal type can have 200 digits after the decimal point.

Any type in C++ ca do that? If i have to deal with strings it's more complex for the operations...

Thanks you in advance !

PS: "• all (external) libraries, except the STL are explicity forbidden"

Comment: Search for `gmp` on google (GNU Multi-Precision library)

Comment: Probably it is a duplicate. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060242/how-to-store-extremely-large-numbers)

Comment: you'll have to deal with strings & implement whatever arithmetic operations your professor asks you to handle.

Comment: "• all (external) libraries, except the STL are explicity forbidden"

Comment: @JónásBalázs: Not a dupe, since OP is forbidden from using an existing library.

Comment: @HaleemurAli: most BigDecimal implementations do not use strings to store such numbers. They use a binary representation, often using BigIntegers internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "big-decimal" type in C++; from your description of the problem, it seems you are subposed to implement your own type with very-high precision.

There is more than one way to do this. Here are some hints/potential directions:

- If d<sub>1</sub> ... d<sub>k</sub> are digits, then the k-digit number 0.d<sub>1</sub>d<sub>2</sub>...d<sub>k</sub>  is equal to 10<sup>-k</sup> * d<sub>1</sub> d<sub>2</sub> ... d<sub>k</sub> (i.e. think mantissa and exponent).
- 200 = lots. Don't try to manually fit your number in enough basic types to get 200 digits.
- The standard library has several classes you could use. Still, you can [hardly go wrong by basing your work on an `std::vector`](http://andybohn.com/almostalwaysvector/). Of course, what exactly you want to put in that vector is a different question.

Comment: Implementing a proper BigDecimal type is not trivial. There are many things to consider. Especially rounding is not so easy, but also things like multi-precision division, multiplication, etc. may be quite a daunting task. Probably more so than all the rest of the VM.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: OP is not supposed to implement a general-purpose BigDecimal, just something at the school project level.

Comment: Even a simple implementation (that does not implement stuff like Karatsuba or Burnikel-Ziegler or other optimizations) is not so easy. Especially rounding and division, but also parsing and displaying won't be very easy, not even with something like BCD or strings. I personally find it a little too much for a school project.