# Variable too large and results in wrong answer

Tags: c++

I've been trying to find a way to store the result of this arithmetic for hours now.

I understand that the data is too large to be stored. But the largest data type my compiler seems to support is unsigned long long.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int num1 = 100000;
   int num2 = 200000;
   int num3 = 300000;
   double num4 = 500000.00;
   unsigned long long product = (num1 * num2 * num3 * num4);

   cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << product << endl;

   // Answer should be 3000000000000000000000.000
   // Result is 18446447556077551616
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you probably need is a library that supports arbitrarily large integers and rational numbers thereof. (Or implement your own)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store extremely large numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060242/how-to-store-extremely-large-numbers)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340511/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-implementing-bigint-in-c

Comment: Well, my main constraint is that I have to use an online compiler because this is a class.

Comment: Maybe use BigIntegers? I remember using them in Java to solve a Project Euler problem. (for numbers excessively large in size)

Comment: Was that actually the result? It didn't end in `5`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assumption: ints are 32-bit.  long longs are 64-bit.

The largest value a 64-bit unsigned can be is:

```
  18446744073709551615
```

You are trying to compute:

```
3000000000000000000000
```

Which won't fit into any 64-bit integer (signed or unsigned)

Let's also break down the problem:

`num1`, `num2`, `num3` are ints, and the expression of multiplying all three ints together

```
   num1 *   num2 *   num3
 100000 * 200000 * 300000
```

As an *integer expression*, `num1*num2*num3` is already overflowing with the values you are multiplying with.  And that's before we've multiplied by `num4`.

Better solution would be to declare num1, num2, and num3 as `long long` so that the above expression will be evaluated as the same type.

But even with this fix, the multiplication of 6 quadrillion times 500000.0 gets evaluated as a double.  That still overflows both double and the 64-bit signed range.

Short answer: You're going to need a big number math library to evaluate numbers in this range.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you really do it convert high numbers with notation or add variable counters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
     int num1;
     int num2;
     int num3;
     int num4;
     int check1;
     double check2;

     cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4;
   
     cout << (num1 * num2 * num3 * num4) << " " << (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4)/4 << endl;
    
     check2 = static_cast<double>((num1 + num2 + num3 + num4)/4.000);
   
if (num1 > (pow(10, 4))){
      num1 = num1 / (pow(10, 5));
      num2 = num2 / (pow(10, 5));
      num3 = num3 / (pow(10, 5));
      num4 = num4 / (pow(10, 5));//note math to add 0 is (5+5+5+5) 20 (0)s
      check1 = (num1 * num2 * num3 * num4);
      cout << check1 << "00000000000000000000.000";
      cout<< setprecision(3) << fixed;
      cout << " " << static_cast<double>(check2) << endl;
   }
   else{
      check1 = (num1 * num2 * num3 * num4)+ .00001; 
      cout<< setprecision(3) << fixed;  
      cout << static_cast<double>(check1) << " " << static_cast<double>(check2) << endl;
}
   return 0;
}
```