# RSA encryption in C++

Tags: c++, math, encryption, rsa

I want to encrypt (RSA) a character to an integer using its ASCII value. Eg. 'a' is encrypted as 48.

For encryption: `c=pow(m,e)%n` where c is cipher text, m is the plain text and (e,n) is the public key.

If pow(m,e) is large say 67^7, it won't fit in *int* or *long*. But if I use *double*, I cannot use it with modulus % operator. So I wrote this function for encryption using a for loop:

```
int encrypt(int m, int e, int n)
{
    int res=m, i;
    for(i=0; i<e-1;i++)
        res=(res*res)%n;
    return res;
}
```

It worked for 67^7mod11 which is 67 but then I came to know it's not actually correct. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You are doing `e-1` squarings, so you compute `m^(2^(e-1))` modulo `n`. You'd want `res = (res*m)%n;` for the simple exponentiation by repeated multiplication algorithm.

Comment: Could you write that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: +1 to @DanielFischer . I was about to go off on modulo-chaining, only to see he already has it, but was missing one loop in the iteration and using the wrong multiplier. Duh. Nice catch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop

```
for(i=0; i<e-1;i++)
    res=(res*res)%n;
```

squares `e-1` times modulo `n`, that means it computes `m^(2^(e-1))` modulo `n`. To compute `m^e` modulo `n` with the simple algorithm, use

```
for(i = 0; i < e-1; ++i)
    res = (res*m) % n;
```

instead.

For a somewhat faster algorithm when the exponent is larger, you can use exponentiation by repeated squaring:

```
res = 1;
while (e > 0) {
    if (e % 2 != 0) {
        res = (m*res) % n;
    }
    m = (m*m) % n;
    e /= 2;
}
return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when using encryption parameters you use "big int" instead of int's.
Exactly for that reason.

There are some suggestions here: 
[Bigint (bigbit) library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055661/bigint-bigbit-library)

Comment: I'm not supposed to use an external library. I'm trying this at home now but have to execute it on Fedora at college where there is no internet access.

Comment: Well then all i can say is implement big int...
Anyway it will be goof practice, specially if you are going to fool around with computerized cryptography.