# What data type can store a factorial of 100

Tags: c++, type-conversion, factorial

Why the below program prints the factorial as 0 for 100 as input. The same factorial can be calculated if the getFact function return type is `long double`, but to get sum of digits I cant appply **mod (%)** operator on long double.

**Note:** size of `unsigned long long` and `long double` is same on my machine.
Kindly suggest for input as 100 What type of data would give correct output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long long int getFactorial(int);
unsigned long long int getSum(unsigned long long int);

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int fact = 1;
    unsigned long long int digsum  = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter a number to find fact := ";
    int num;
    std::cin >> num;
    fact = getFactorial(num);
    std::cout << num <<"'s factorial is = " << fact << std::endl;
    digsum = getSum(fact);
    std::cout << sizeof(unsigned long long int) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(long double) << std:: endl;
    std::cout << "Sum of the digits in the number" << num << "! is :=" <<  digsum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

unsigned long long int getFactorial(int num)
{

    if(num == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (num * getFactorial(num - 1));
}


unsigned long long int getSum(unsigned long long int fact)
{
    if(fact == 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int temp = 0;
        temp = fact % 10;
        return (temp + getSum(fact/10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Any standard type is too small for this. You can use boost, or something else.

Comment: https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Comment: [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: @ForEveR as I have mentioned in the question `long double` works fine to calculate the factorial the same answer I have verified using google calculator. But the problem is with `unsigned long long int` which is same 8 bytes as `long double`.

Comment: try visualizing the result of multiplications in an array of integers, with each digit occupying an index in array. Design a solution using array as storage type.

Comment: @Nik the factorial of 100 can be stored using `long double`.

Comment: I recommend to all please run the program using `long double` as getFact return type.

Comment: @Surfing_SO No, 100! has 157 decimal digits, 525 in binary. The Google result is an approximation.

Comment: Please see the link of the image for code and output.


http://i.stack.imgur.com/hrTeS.png

Comment: @molbdnilo then how come my system also gives the same output with `long double`. Please execute the getFact with `long double` if you can.

Comment: @Surfing_SO A `long double` and `long long` are **completely different concepts** of holding numbers! Though they may occupy the same amount of physical space.

Comment: @Surfing_SO Your computation has exactly the same problem as Google's. That doesn't make either of them correct.

Comment: @molbdnilo will you put some light on where exactly I am going wrong, and what is with this approximation, kindly explain

Comment: @Surfing_SO Floating point numbers can be very large, but their precision is limited - approximately 16 decimal digits for an IEEE double. So you can't compute factorials greater than 18! exactly using them.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to calculate this without a big int class. It should be possible to use log10 for this but I am not sure about the loss of precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an approximation you can use double. (Beware integer arithmetic is different from double). You can use `log` calculation or multiplication to estimate `100!`.

But because you want the sum of digits, you need precise result, you would need some [big integer library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055661/bigint-bigbit-library). You can google for big integer.

Or you can store big [number as string](http://codepad.org/T2AcSJzN) and perform your calculation (product) the way we learnt in school using pen and paper.

Answer (score 3):

use double instead of long long int, as for 100!, long long int is too short to hold the result.

```
double getFactorial(double num)
{
    if (num <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (num * getFactorial(num - 1));
}
```

Comment: Using `==` for double is dangerous.

Comment: why not just compare against 1? I.e. `if (num <= 1) return 1`?

Answer (score 0):

With `long double` I compared the results and works well until 25, from that there is error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

long double factorial(long double n)
{
    if (n<=1)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    long double fact;
    for(long double i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        fact=factorial(i);
        cout<<i<<"!= "<<setprecision(0)<<fixed<<fact<<endl;;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did u try `double` only?? when `double` alone works fine then what is the significance of your answer which, according to you, works well until 25 only?